# Pandas - grouping a subset of a dataframe and changing column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So I have a dataframe and I'm struggling to group a subset of rows within it, here are a couple of lines of the dataframe (I only kept the important columns for clarity):
[image]

How can first filter the dataframe on only lines that contain 'Myprotein NL' for column B and 'CLOTHING' for the C column, group those lines on column D and then change the title. The change in the title will be a split and join so that the size gets removed. So it will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will drop duplicates if all three of those columns are duplicated. Then you could do a find and replace. Probably not the best method but it would work

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['merchant_name', 'commision_group', 'mpn'], keep='first')
df = df.replace('MP Mensengage........ - XS' ), 'same thing without the size')
```

Comment: The only problem is that I only want to edit the titles of those duplicates..